# Q: Is there any way to use two GET routes with two different methods on a single controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Instead of using two profile controllers for two user types, is it possible to use one controller with two different methods to show profiles of each user types ?

so far only Applicant route works, but if switch the order the other one shows `404 | Not Found`.

```
Route::get('/accounts/{applicant}', 'ProfileController@applicant');
Route::get('/accounts/{employer}', 'ProfileController@employer');
```

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function applicant(Applicant $applicant)
    {
        return view('applicant.show', compact('applicant'));
    }

    public function employer(Employer $employer)
    {
        return view('employer.show', compact('employer'));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: The issue is the URL will look like `/accounts/10` and if you have both applicant and employer with the same id you can't differentiate. If you can't have the same id then you could potentially just have one action and branch based on what kind of ID you get

Comment: It is actually possible using route parameter matching, but if you dont have distinctly different formats for the paramaters, ie. you are using id for both then you cannot do it. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints. You can even tweak how laravel does its route-model binding for specific models, so even the controller is theoretically possible

Comment: Parameter matching is the answer, the OP is using different parameters :)

Comment: Indeed true, it's not possible. thank you all for your answers! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. There is no difference in the request itself on both routes. Either you use another route, or make a method which can handle both *applicant* and *employer*, but you'll still need to figure out how to differentiate these two.

Comment: Using a different route sounds pretty much easy for me at the moment, thank you @sykez.